# Inferring types whilst eliding moves/copies without a macro

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, c++11

Consider the following simple `make_pair` class:

```
template <class X, class Y>
struct Pair
{
    X x;
    Y y;
};
```

Also, we'll make a simple class to show any moves/copies:

```
struct C
{
    C(int n_) : n(n_) {};
    C(const C& x) { n = x.n; std::cout << "Copy: " << n << std::endl; }
    C(C&& x)      { n = x.n; std::cout << "Move: " << n << std::endl; }
    int n;
};
```

We can then run:

```
auto z1 = Pair<C, C>{C(1),C(2)};
```

And there is no output, `C` is not moved or copied.

However, we have to specify the types in the constructor `Pair`. Lets say we want to infer these. We could do something like this:

```
template <class X, class Y>
Pair<X, Y> make_pair(X&& x, Y&& y)
{
    return Pair<X, Y>{std::forward<X>(x), std::forward<Y>(y)};
}
```

And then we can do:

```
auto z2 = make_pair(C(3),C(4));
```

But this prints:

```
Move: 3
Move: 4
```

Not a problem if `C` is a heap allocated type, but if a stack allocated type, a move is basically a copy.

But then lets define this macro:

```
#define MAKE_PAIR(x,y) decltype(make_pair(x,y)){x,y}
```

Then we can do:

```
auto z3 = MAKE_PAIR(C(5),C(6));
```

And this does type deduction AND doesn't need a move. But we need to make a macro, which I feel is a bit messy, and also stops us from using operators to do this sort of thing.

Is there a solution that does the following:

(1) Deduces types (like 2 and 3)
(2) Doesn't require a copy or move (like 1 and 3)
(3) Doesn't require a macro (like 1 and 2)

The best I can get is two out of three, but surely three out of three is possible? I can't imagine C++ would force one to use macros to get the behaviour I was after, as apparently C++ is moving away from macros.

The code is [here](http://ideone.com/A6DqH1).

Comment: [I can make it happen for copies](http://liveworkspace.org/code/fab73a188be2b1b2bcf244dba4047b8f), not sure about moves. (Note: Your `make_pair` will create a `Pair<T&, U&>` if you pass lvalues. ;) As such, no copies.)

Comment: If your stack-based classes are so large that this is a problem, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @Xeo: Hehe, I was wondering if that was by design or if I should say anything. A little `remove_reference` or `decay` may well be in order in that maker function.

Comment: @KerrekSB,Xeo: It wasn't particularly by design, but it's not the main concern. The main issue I'm getting at is that the temporaries should be constructed in place. They are in examples (1) and (3), but not (2).

Comment: When asking my compiler to optimize, while the outputs from the special members are still performed, all references to `C`, `Pair` and `make_pair` are removed anyway. So sure, the copies are not elided in the sense that their side-effects are kept. But the objects are not here anyway. Considering that the side-effects were put here presumably for instrumentation, then I don't really know what the question is about.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't imagine C++ would force one to use macros to get the behaviour I was after, as apparently C++ is moving away from macros.

The behavior you're after was never guaranteed by the standard in the first place. Elision is an *optimization*; it is not required for any implementation. So none of them are guaranteed to do what you want, though obviously some of them at least allow it to be possible.

Forwarding effectively makes elision impossible; there's nothing that can be done about that fact. Perfect forwarding is all about references and reference collapsing; elision is about values initializing value parameters, which it can't know about at the initial call site.

In real-world situations, this should not be an issue. Most of the things that are actually worth eliding are things where copying is *expensive*. Copying a few `int`s or `floats`, especially for a trivial class, will likely not even show up as a blip on a profiler. In the vast majority of cases, objects that are expensive to copy are so because they hold some kind of resource, such as allocated memory. So most types that are expensive to copy can also be moveable, and thus will move cheaply.

In any case, yes, if you want to have the possibility of elision, you cannot use forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you are still having to specify the types once.  If your goal is to avoid having to specify the types more than once, you can do this:

```
auto z = Pair<C,C>{3,4};
```

Note that this even works if you have more complex constuctors:

```
struct C {
  C(int,int) { }
  C(int) { }
};

auto z = Pair<C,C>{{1,2},3};
```

and requires no copies.